# CodeIgniter create n-level deep navigation

Tags: php, codeigniter, navigation, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I'd like some help please. I have created dynamic a menu navbar that displays the menu items accoridning to the order that  I've set them. I'm using this [nestedsortable](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) plugin, to order my menu items, but currently my menu has only 2 levels, so basicly it goes like this:

```
Item1
Item2
 > Subitem2.1
 > Subitem2.2
Item3
etc etc.
```

What I'd like to do is make it with n-levels, so basicly something like this:

```
Item1
Item2
  > Subitem2.1
    >> Subitem2.1.1
  > Subitem2.2
Item3
etc etc.
```

and each item can go n-level deep. The problem is that if I set a new order to my menu items that is more than 2 levels deep I get an error and the order is not stored in the database. How can I fix this please ???

The database structure is this:

```
table: Menu
id (pk)
menu_item
parent_id // it is the id of the parent menu item
order
```

Here are my main (model) functions:

```
// save the order of the menu items
public function save_order($items){
    if (count($items)>0) {
        foreach ($items as $order => $item) {
            if ($item['item_id'] != '') {

                $data = array(
                    'parent_id' => (int)$item['parent_id'], 
                    'order'     => $order
                );

                $this->db->set($data)
                ->where($this->_primary_key, $item['item_id'])
                ->update($this->_table_name);
            }
        }
    }
}

// fetch the menu items (parents & children) from the last order set
public function get_menu(){

    $this->db->select('id, menu_item, parent_id');
    $this->db->order_by('parent_id, order');
    $menu_items = $this->db->get('menu')->result_array();

    $arr = array();
    foreach ($menu_items as $item) {

        // the item has no parent
        if (!$item['parent_id']) {
            $arr[$item['id']] = $item; // e.g. $arr(4 => array())
        } // the item is a child
        else {
            // e.g. $arr(4 => array('children' => array()))
            $arr[$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
 }
```

### Update

For additional help: I did a test and dumped the array of the items on the screen in both cases:

**1st case:** with 2 levels (as it is currently): I set the items with this order

- Item1
- Item2

  - Item4
- Item3
- Item5

and the result looks like this, as expected:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [menu_item] => Item1
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [menu_item] => Item2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [menu_item] => Item4
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [menu_item] => Item3
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [menu_item] => Item5
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

)
```

**2nd case:** with n-levels: I tried to set the menu items with this order:

- Item1
- Item2

  - Item5

    - Item4
- Item3

and the result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [menu_item] => Item1 
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [menu_item] => Item2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [menu_item] => Item5
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [menu_item] => Item3
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [menu_item] => Item4
                            [parent_id] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is the case where I get the error and not working. The errors I get are:

Message: Undefined index: page_id
Message: Undefined index: menu_item

in my view file:

```
function nav($menu_items, $child = false){
    $output = '';

    if (count($array)) {
        $output .= ($child === false) ? '<ol class="sortable">' : '<ol>' ;

        foreach ($menu_items as $item) {
            $output .= '<li id="list_' . $item['id'] . '">'; // here is the line of the 1st error
            $output .= '<div>' . $item['menu_item'] . '</div>'; // 2nd error

            //check if there are any children
            if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
                $output .= nav($item['children'], true);
            }
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ol>';
    }
    return $output;
}


echo nav($menu_items);
```

Comment: `I get an error` What kind of error? What does `$items` look like (in `save_order()` function)?

Comment: I did an update to the post. Please review

Comment: @Lykos i cannot clearly understand what you are trying to say. Also i cannot find `page_id` variable in your code and your array in second case is not uniform (4th index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the database output, it seems the items are stored in the database correctly. And the problem belongs to the `get_menu()` method and its algorithm to create the output.

In order to create a **n-level** deep menu, you should iterate through the items recursively.

Here we go:

```php
function prepareList(array $items, $pid = 0)
{
    $output = array();

    # loop through the items
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        # Whether the parent_id of the item matches the current $pid
        if ((int) $item['parent_id'] == $pid) {

            # Call the function recursively, use the item's id as the parent's id
            # The function returns the list of children or an empty array()
            if ($children = prepareList($items, $item['id'])) {

                # Store all children of the current item
                $item['children'] = $children;
            }

            # Fill the output
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

You could use the above logic as a **helper** function (in CodeIgniter) or a **private** method within your Controller class.

Then call that function/method inside `get_menu()` method as follows:

```php
public function get_menu()
{
    $this->db->select('id, menu_item, parent_id');
    $this->db->order_by('parent_id, order');
    $menu_items = $this->db->get('menu')->result_array();

    return prepareList($menu_items);
}
```

**Note:** I used the `prepareList()` as a helper (global) function. If you decide to use that as a private method, you should replace the function name by `$this->prepareList()` everywhere (even inside the function itself).

Here is the **[Online Demo](http://codepad.org/Q7qxfwQI)**.

Comment: I 've found this library ( https://github.com/olimortimer/ci-nested-sets ) which works with nested sets, but I haven't found any documentation on how to use it. Have you ever used this or another similar library, and is there any help/tutorials or user-guide??

Comment: @Lykos No I have not, sorry. I don't use CodeIgniter anymore.